# ¿Cómo resetear los diseños de un form-wizard que se encuentra en un modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando  el formulario  Form-Wizard de esta plantilla AdminBSB

https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/pages/forms/form-wizard.html

la plantilla utiliza este plugin    jquery-steps.js

lo e añadido a un modal , las funciones estan funcionando correctamente pero cuando inserto el registro se cierra el modal y cuando lo vuelvo abrir se queda en el ultimo paso y quiero que cada vez que abra el modal se el form wizard y me seleccione el primer paso su respectivo contenido y con sus campos vacios.

así queda el formulario despues de hacer un registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así deberia de estar cada vez que inserte y vuelva a abrir el modal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Probaste configurar en las opciones del plugin el paso con el que inicia? Según vi en la documentación se llama startIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregar esta funcion en jquery.steps.js

```js
$.fn.steps.reset = function() {
  var wizard = this,
    options = getOptions(this),
    state = getState(this);
  if (state.currentIndex > 0) {
    goToStep(wizard, options, state, 0);
    for (i = 1; i < state.stepCount; i++) {
      var stepAnchor = getStepAnchor(wizard, i);
      stepAnchor.parent().removeClass("done")._enableAria(false);
    }
  }
};
```

y llamarla a la hora de abrir el modal

```js
$ ("#wizard").steps('reset');
```